# Callback from tweet button in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, mobile-safari

I want users to be able to share a page. It's specific for iOS users. Best practice would be to use the share button from Safari itself, so users don't have to login, etc. But I want to track if the link has been shared through Twitter/Facebook. Is there some kind of callback you can monitor server-side or some other way, to tracks sharing from a webpage on iOS (6)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd have to make a link that forwarded to a server you managed, record what information you'd like out of the link, and then forward that user to the actual link you want to send them to. You're basically intercepting them on their way to the site they want, and can track what you want from that link. A lot of sites employ this practice.

Take for example in Facebook, whenever you click an external link there you actually click a link thats first handled by Facebooks servers to record your action, then forwards you on to the correct site.

Comment: I understand the part to generate a unique token in the url and serve this as url address. But when you click on the share button and Twitter, it just takes the url from the address bar within the post. So the link is there, but it doesn't actually 'touch' it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about server side, but you can track when the user completes a post in the iOS SDK. Here's an example of a `TWTweetComposeViewController` completion handler that will inform you when the user has successfully posted the tweet. I'd give you a Facebook example, but iOS 6 is still under NDA.

Additionally, there's no need to do this in Safari. If the user has linked their Twitter account in system preferences, they will not be prompted to login using a `TWTweetComposeViewController` and the same should holder true for the iOS 6 Facebook composer.

```
[tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {

    switch (result) {
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            break;
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
              //some code representing a successful tweet here! 
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

Comment: I can't have an SDK implementation, so we don't have access to any controller within iOS itself. It needs to work from the browser.

Comment: @user1607016 Well good luck to you! Sorry I couldn't be more help, I'm not really a web guy.